# Angular JS Parse Syntax Issue While ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and facing parse syntax issue. I am just scratching my head. Tried many solutions but stuck.... Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Below is the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Record in Records">
                   <td>
                      <div class="checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="{{Record.id}}" name="{{'chk_'+Record.id}}" ng-click="{{'Name.changeStatus('+Record.id+',Name.checkStatus'+Record.id+')'" ng-model="{{'Name.checkStatus'+Record.id}}" ng-init="{{'Name.checkStatus'+Record.id}}={{'Name.getTrueFalse('+Record.status+')'}}"  />
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onaftersave="{{'Name.UpdateRecord('+Record.id+',$data)'}}" ng-model="{{'Name.name'+Record.id}}" editable-text="{{'Name.name'+Record.id}}" e-style="color: #333" e-required ng-init="{{'Name.name'+Record.id}}='{{Record.name}}'" ><span class="{{Record.status == 0 ? 'cross' : ''}}">{{Record.name}}</span></a></td>
                  <td class="right-align"><button type="button" ng-click="Name.deleteRecord(Record.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your bindings are wrong.

For instance this:

```
ng-click="{{'Name.changeStatus('+Record.id+',Name.checkStatus'+Record.id+')'"
```

Should be written:

```
ng-click="Name.changeStatus(Record.id, Name.checkStatus+Record.id)'"
```

Basically what you write in `ng-click` or `ng-init` are *expressions* which will be executed by angular. So they shouldn't be string with quotes `'` but instead an actual bit a code.

`ng-model` is a two-ways binding, which means you need to pass a variable here, such as `ng-model="myModel"` or `ng-model="myObject.myProperty"`

Too many things are wrong in the code and we cannot guess what you're trying to achieve without the code of the `onaftersave` and `editable-text` directives.